# Como hace histogramas de un dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

alguien podría ayudarme a hacer un histograma de una matriz que tengo.

intente pero me sale solamente un histograma con una barra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estos son los datos:

```
    product_id
24852    18726
13176    15480
21137    10894
21903     9784
47626     8135
47766     7409
47209     7293
16797     6494
26209     6033
27966     5546
dtype: int64
```

y asi es como obtengo los datos:

```
#Productos mas vendidos
rep = Train.groupby(['product_id']).size()
rep = rep.sort_values(ascending = False)
print(rep.head(10))
rep.hist(bins = 10)
```

se supone que deberian salir 10 barras en total para cada producto pero solo me arroja una barra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo `rep.hist` generas un histograma que representa el número de veces que aparece cada `size` en la serie, con un ejemplo más pequeño se ve más claro:

```
import pandas as pd

Train = pd.DataFrame({"product_id": (24852, 13176, 21137, 21903, 47626,
                                     13176, 13176, 21903, 21903, 47626,
                                     24852, 21903, 21137, 21903, 47626,
                                     13176, 13176, 47626, 21903, 47626)})

rep = Train.groupby(['product_id']).size()
rep.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)


>>> rep

product_id
21903    6
47626    5
13176    5
24852    2
21137    2
dtype: int64
```

> ```
> >>> rep.hist(bins=10)
> ```
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que en realidad buscas creo que es un simple gráfico de barras que relacione cada `product_id` (índice de la serie) con su cantidad:

> ```
> >>> ax = rep.plot.bar()    
> >>> ax.set_ylabel("Counts")
> ```
>
> [image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias, era eso lo que buscaba